# Custom UIResponder subclass

Tags: ios, uikit, uiresponder

Is it possible to set up a custom `UIResponder` subclass? I need to implement a listener for `UIEvent`s (specifically remote control events) that will be delivered through out the course of the app's lifecycle.

I am trying to avoid using `UIViewController`s (will be dealloced at some point) and `AppDelegate` (would like to not burden it if possible) if possible.

Comment: It seems like the AppDelegate is the ideal place to put this code. One of the bullet points mentioned in the AppDelegate protocol reference is, "It responds to events that target the app itself and are not specific to your app’s views or view controllers." I don't think you should worry about burdening it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you *can* subclass UIResponder and you *can* make an instance of that subclass. The problem is getting that instance into the responder chain, so that its UIResponder methods are actually called, and in such a way that the rest of the responder chain doesn't break. This might be possible — I've certainly done it in Cocoa on the desktop, though never in UIKit on an iOS device — but you would do much better, in my opinion, to give some introspective thought to why you have this peculiar aversion to putting the code where it obviously wants to go (in a UIViewController or in the app delegate).

Comment: I am not sure if it's a certainty that this responsibility belongs in the app delegate. It's custom events that should arguably be handled by a custom object (and not funnel through the AD), much like rotation events or touch events.

Comment: But that's a trivial point of architectural aesthetics; you can always break that functionality off into a helper object belonging to the app delegate or a view controller (see _Design Patterns_). That's not the point. The point is that Cocoa is a _framework_: that means you must put your code where it will in fact be called. An entry point in a view controller or the app delegate is where your code will be called. Use it and move on.

Comment: Sure, I am not going to fight the framework. You were asking me for the reason why I was hoping to make a cleaner break. "Peculiar aversion" indicated you wanted me to clarify. It may be trivial, but if it was possible, I would use it. Hence the original question.